# Flatten matrix in python :

Tags: python, python-3.x

A trick when you want to flatten a matrix `X` of shape `(a,b,c,d)` to a matrix `X_flatten` of shape `(b ∗∗ c ∗∗ d, a)` is to use:

```
X_flatten = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1).T
```

I read this trick in coursera DL course, how does this work? Where did `-1` come from and what does it mean?

Comment: How are your matrices represented? In numpy?

Answer (score 2):

X.shape[0] returns the first dimension of your original array:

```
X = np.random.rand(4, 4, 4, 4)
print(X.shape)
```

results in

```
(4, 4, 4, 4)
```

and therefore

```
X.shape[0]
```

returns

```
4
```

Using the reshape command, you can omit one of the target matrix dimensions by using -1 as a placeholder,
because one of the dimensions can be inferred by numpy.

I.e. by supplying the 4 from X.shape[0], numpy knows what the remaining first dimension must be for the array to contain all your values.

In the example

```
new_X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1).T
print(new_X.shape)
```

it is

```
(64, 4)
```

which would be equivalent to calling

```
new_X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 64).T
print(new_X.shape)
```

The .T function just transposes the array resulting from the reshape command.

Comment: Thanks for  the very lucid explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the same in, Using the basic concepts of python

```
nested_list=[10,20,[30,40,[50]],[80,[10,[20]],90],60]
flat_list=[]
def unpack(list1):
    for item in list1:
        try:
            len(item)
            unpack(item)
        except:
            flat_list.append(item)
unpack(nested_list)
print (flat_list)
```